# Emoji Softkeyboard like Whatsapp in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

> I am `interested` in creating **Whatsapp like Emoji keyboard in Android**. I am successful in creating `Emoji keyboard`.

Now i want to add two scrolls to my **Custom keyboard(InputMethod)**.

**First** is the `horizontal scroll` above the `keyboard`(like in kitkat) to select categories Like(`Nature,People,Place,Symbols`) .

**Secondly.** I want to add a **vertical GridView of Emoji**. So no need to click the `categories` again and again in order to get the full list.

**What have I tried so far.**

I have created my `input.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.zeuxislo.emojikeyboard.EmojiKeyboardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground" >
        </com.zeuxislo.emojikeyboard.EmojiKeyboardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wao what a keyBoard"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And in `SoftKeyboard.java`

```
public View onCreateInputView() 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

        testInput = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_input, null);

        mInputView = (KeyboardView) testInput.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

        this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
        //this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
        this.mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        this.mInputView.setKeyboard(this.mQwertyKeyboard);
        return this.mInputView;
    }
```

> Also tried putting TextView above and below the layout. But it doesn't display. How can I do it?

And I also tried adding a `HorizontalScrollView` like

```
<Keyboard  android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height" android:horizontalGap="0.0px" android:verticalGap="0.0px"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <Row  android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="-1009" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1010" android:keyLabel="ABC" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1011" android:keyLabel="123" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1012" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e415" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1013" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e04a" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1014" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e033" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1015" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e01d" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1016" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e214" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="-1017" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return" />

         <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="-1021" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1022" android:keyLabel="ABC" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1023" android:keyLabel="123" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1024" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e415" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:codes="-1025" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e04a" />
    </Row>
  </HorizontalScrollView>

</Keyboard >
```

Comment: BTW: If you make a Keyboard, you potentialy programmed a keylogger. Have a look on the rights you describe in the Manivest, avoid if possible Internet and FileWriting. I would never use a keyboard haveing access to the net..

Comment: How can i earn without adding internet permission?

Comment: idk.. make a demo and a premium one? But you see my point? If you got acces to the internet, who says that you are not sending everything i entered to your server? including my passwords, emailaddresses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, all you are doing for the emoji keyboard is to create a view of the size of the keyboard and then populating that view with image files corresponding to the emoji's. each image acts like a button and delivers the appropriate emoji to the inputConnection.

The best implementation for an emoji keyboard I found was that of [sliding emoji-Keyboard](https://github.com/klinker24/Android-SlidingEmojiKeyboard). I was able to fork the project and do clean ups and enhanced it quite a bit. You can take a look at my [emoji-Keyboard](https://github.com/flide/Android-SlidingEmojiKeyboard/) to try and understand the methodology I employed.

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 UPDATE:

This is the best library I've found: [GitHub](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji).
It works perfectly and has a great look, you can even choose which style of emojis you want (including iOS, Google, Twitter). The usage is also quiet simple and well explained.